# Am I right in this discrete mathematics question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$A = \{0, 1, 2\}$

$B = \{x \in R\mid−1 \le x \lt 3\}$

$C = \{x \in R\mid−1 \lt x \lt 3\}$

$D = \{x \in Z\mid−1 \lt x \lt 3\}$

$E = \{x \in Z+ \mid−1 \lt x \lt 3\}$

I put that $A=D$, $A=C$, and $C=D$

$A\not=E$ because $E$ is looking for just positive integer numbers and since $0$ is not a positive number, then they are not equal.

However Chegg solutions says that $A=E$ which makes me think that their answer is wrong.

Any thoughts?

Comment: By the way, $A\neq C$ and $C \neq D$.

Comment: Could you explain how 
$A\not=C$  . A has elements 0,1, and 2. In C x represents anything greater than -1 and less than 3. Wouldnt that meet the criteria?

Comment: $C$ contains all the real numbers including those which are not integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about A not being equal to E, so long as you are sure that $\mathbb{Z}_+$ is the intended domain. If the domain were $\mathbb{N}$, A would equal E, so I'd double check that, but if it is presented just like you presented it, the Chegg solution is wrong.

Comment: Perfect. Now in regards to the others is Arpan correct? It makes sense now that Arpan explained it but I just want to double check. I mean 0,1,2 are not only integers but they are also rational numbers

Comment: The problem is not that A has elements not contained in C (because it does not), but that C has elements not contained in A. For example, $1/5$ is in C but not A. That makes the sets not equal. A is, however, contained in C. Maybe that is what is tripping you up.

Comment: YES. This is it and this is what I had trouble understanding. Very interesting.